# A face and all its neighbors: terminology?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, simplicial-complexes, polyhedra

Suppose $F$ is a face of a 2-complex, and $F_1,\dotsc,F_n$ are the faces that are adjacent to (i.e., share an edge with) $F$. Is there a standard term for a collection of faces of the form $\{F,F_1,\dotsc,F_n\}$? Note that under (Vertex,Edge,Face) $\leftrightarrow$ (Face,Edge,Vertex) duality, this is dual to what graph theorists call the closed neighborhood of a vertex $v$.

Comment: Perhaps the coclosure, i.e. closure of the dual?